# Cloud Firestore equivalent of AppEngine/Datastore Memcache and Keys-only queries?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Using keys-only queries on the datastore and then fetching the entities from memcache is an inexpensive mechanism for reading tons of entities at once. For example, a keys-only query could be made for 1000 keys, which can be used to fetch the entities from memcahce, without having to perform many, if any, datastore reads.

Does/will Cloud Firestore offer anything like this?

Answer (score 14):

Cloud Firestore does not support this. It is something being considered but we have no timeframe to share.

Comment: Upvoted to show my support for keys-only queries on Firestore. ;-)

Comment: Is it like we need wait for years to see a feature on firebase :|. Also, firebase being more transparent related to roadmaps will create interest aiming lots of devs. Pls pls consider.

Comment: Is this still the case? If so, any updates? Also, some clarification would be nice on the following link. It seems to indicate that DocumentIds CAN be returned by themselves, but it's not clear as to whether or not this query option counts as a full set of document reads on the result set if only the Ids are returned, or if it counts as a "small operation".

"An empty Select call will produce a query that returns only document IDs."

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Query.Select